# Imageresizer: Image URL without width and height query parameter (use original size)

Tags: image, imageresizer

We use Imageresizer (http://imageresizing.net) to resize images by using image URLs like

- http://host.com/path/to/image/file.jpg.ashx?width=50
- http://host.com/path/to/image/file.jpg.ashx?height=50

which works like a charm.

We also use other Imageresizer features like the 404-filter to output a default image in the case of that the requested image does not exist.

My question is: Is it possible to use Imageresizer features like the 404-filter without providing the width and/or height query parameter? The idea is, that the Imageresizer uses the original width and height values.

Whe I try to use an image URL like http://host.com/path/to/image/file.jpg.ashx?404=/path/to/image/file.jpg I get a 404 error.

Thanks in advance.
  Jan

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not with ImageResizer 3.X. ImageResizer doesn't touch requests that don't require processing, and during request inspection there's nothing to indicate that `http://host.com/path/to/image/file.jpg.ashx?404=/path/to/image/file.jpg` would need any image processing.

In fact, just based on the URL, it would be assumed that it's actually a physical .ashx handler taking an arbitrary parameter. ImageResizer tries to play nice with everything else running on your site.

You can catch 404s exceptions yourself at the HttpApplication level, however. It's just outside ImageResizer's jurisdiction to do this kind of thing.

Another option is to use a no-op command to trigger ImageResizer for the URL, such as `&cache=always`

Comment: Thanks for your answer process=always does the trick. Setting process=no and using only the 404 parameter results in a 404 error page.

Comment: Actually, try `cache=always` instead. `process=always` may reduce your image quality slightly.